# SendGrid doesn't send email from Azure Windows 2012 VM

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio, email, azure

I set up SendGrid account and got key and pw.
My VisualBasic 2015 console app runs DeliverAsync without error, but email doesn't get to Internet receipients (my Hotmail account).
Also, the task.wait() throws exception "Bad username / password", which is posted at the end

Wireshark on Azure shows no SMTP, but I don't know if SendGrid uses SMTP.

Here is the app:

```
' Create the email object first, then add the properties.
Dim myMessage As SendGridMessage
myMessage = New SendGridMessage()

' Add the message properties.
myMessage.From = New MailAddress("<my email addr>")

' Add multiple addresses to the To field.



myMessage.AddTo("<destination email addr 1>")
myMessage.AddTo("<destination email addr 2>")
myMessage.AddTo("<destination email addr 3>")

myMessage.Subject = "Testing the SendGrid Library 2"

'Add the HTML and Text bodies
myMessage.Html = "<p>Hello World!</p>"
myMessage.Text = "Hello World plain text!"

Dim credentials As NetworkCredential


credentials = New NetworkCredential("apikey", "<my api pw>")
transportWeb = New Web(credentials)
    Dim task = transportWeb.DeliverAsync(myMessage)
    Try
        task.wait()
    Catch ex As AggregateException
        Stop  '<<<<<<<<<  I GET:  "Bad username / password"

    Catch

    End Try
```

EXCEPTION DETAILS:
"Bad username / password"

Comment: SendGrid's .NET client is open source. If you don't know whether it's using SMTP or another protocol to send your email, just [browse the code](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-csharp/blob/master/SendGrid/SendGridMail/Transport/Web.cs) and look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working by creating new VB web app instead of win app.
VB > create new proj > web app > MVC and then props > references > NU.. Mgr > search SendGrid > Install, and that's it.

Answer (score 0):

[DeliverAsync](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-csharp/blob/master/SendGrid/SendGridMail/Transport/Web.cs) returns a [Task](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task(v=vs.110).aspx), so you need to await the task.

```
Await transportWeb.DeliverAsync(myMessage)
```

Of course, to use the `await` keyword your method needs to be marked as `async`. If you don't want to do that, then you can manually wait on the task.

```
Dim task = transportWeb.DeliverAsync(myMessage)
task.Wait()
```

You should familiarize yourself with the [Task-based Asynchronous Pattern (TAP)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175(v=vs.110).aspx). Often when a function name ends in `-Async` then it uses TAP.

Comment: @DougNull That's good. That means it's actually attempting to deliver. An aggregate exception will contain more information about what caused it to be thrown, inspect the properties of the exception. If you're unable to fix, then you can edit the exception details into your question, then comment and let me know and I'll help if I can.

Comment: I posted exception details above.

Comment: @DougNull We don't need all the stack trace etc. Look at what you posted. It says "Check Errors for a list of errors returned by the API". So do that. Check the Errors property and see what they are.

Comment: I don't know where "Errors" is.

Comment: @DougNull You need to catch the AggregateException. It will have an InnerException property. Access that. Whatever type it is (perhaps it's an `InvalidApiRequestException`) will have an Errors property that is a string array containing the error messages. Either inspect those errors using Visual Studio's debugger, or write them to some sort of output such as trace or your error page.

Comment: "Bad username / password"

Comment: Well that seems pretty straightforward then. Check their site and see what your username and password should be.